# Sublime Text 3 Build Python Code without using Virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, sublimetext3, anaconda

I'm trying to use Sublime Text 3 to execute Python script. After downloading the ST3 packages `Anaconda` and `Virtualenv`, I added my Anaconda virtualenv path to the ST3 package `Virtualenv` and activated one of the virtualenv that the ST3 plugin found. The Build System in ST3 has been set to `Python + Virtualenv`

**Problem:** Building a python script that imports a module `import pyodbc` that is already installed in the virtualenv (presumably activated within ST3) causes an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/x/testPython/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pyodbc
ImportError: No module named pyodbc
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/x/testPython/test.py"]
[dir: /Users/x/testPython]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Why is ST3 not finding the module even though its installed in the currently activated virtualenv?

**my.sublime-project**

```
{
    "build_systems":
    [
        {
            "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
            "name": "Anaconda Python Builder",
            "selector": "source.python",
            "shell_cmd": "/Users/x/anaconda/envs/test/bin/python -u \"$file\""
        }
    ],
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "follow_symlinks": true,
            "path": "/Users/x/testPython"
        }
    ],
    "settings":
    {
        "python_interpreter": "/Users/x/anaconda/envs/test/bin/python"
    },
    "virtualenv": "/Users/x/anaconda/envs/test"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `Anaconda Python Builder` build system? That's the one that's using your virtualenv's version of Python...

Comment: @MattDMo Tried the `Anaconda Python Builder` builds system and its still not finding the python package installed into the virtualenv I activated using the `Virtualenv` ST3 package

Comment: Have you tried not using the virtualenv package (i.e., don't activate anything) and just using the Anaconda build system?